# Induction from trivial representation and number of irreducibles

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, $S$ a subgroup and $K$ a field, whose characteristic does not divide the group order. Let $\pi$ be the trivial representation of $S$. Are there criteria in how many irreducible representations of $G$ the induced representation $\pi^G$ decomposes?

I know that the number is at least 2 (a trivial and another one). Is there also an upper limit?

Comment: The upper bound is, of course, the dimension $|G/S|$, which is attained when $G$ is abelian. What else do you want to know?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Well, that seems to be what OP  is asking.  Maybe that should be an answer.

Comment: I mean, it's not a very interesting upper bound, but if the OP wants more they should be more specific.

Comment: Note that $\pi^G(g)$ is the number of fixed points in the action of $G$ on the set $X$ of cosets of $S$ in $G$. The inner product $\langle \pi^G,\pi^G \rangle$ is equal to the number of orbits of $G$ on $X \times X$. So, for example, $\pi^G$ has exactly two constituents if and only if $G$ acts 2-transitively on $X$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am looking for a list of interesting bounds, which are more precisely than the index. E.j. linke in Derek Holts answer. @Derek Holt: If I take your example, isn't there a pendency on the field $K$?

Comment: Is this true even if $K$ is not a splitting field?

Comment: It is true for any field $K$ (of characteristic 0 or coprime to $|G|$) that $G$ 2-transitive on $X$ implies that $\pi^G$ has exactly 2 constituents. I am not sure about the converse. Perhaps $\pi^G$ could have two constituents one of which was not absolutely irreducible (so it would split into algebraically conjugate characters over an algebraic closure of $K$), but I do not know any examples.